# AlertDialog within Options Menu

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to create an Alert Dialog with a list of single-choice items (radio buttons). This dialog will be invoked when the user clicks one of the two options menu.

Unfortunately, I am unable to get this code to work. When I click on the first option menu (settings), nothing appears. But when I click on the second option menu, the toast appears as it should. I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could point out the obvious error.

The following is the code listing for the Alert Dialog and the Options Menu:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

ProgressDialog msgInitGPS = null;
final CharSequence[] items = {"m/s", "km/h", "mph"};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.settings: AlertDialog.Builder UnitSelection = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                            UnitSelection.setTitle("Select Unit");
                            UnitSelection.setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                            AlertDialog alert = UnitSelection.create();
                            break;

        case R.id.help:     Toast.makeText(this, "This will launch the Help screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: I think you're missing `alert.show()`. Or alternatively `UnitSelection.show()` should create and show this dialog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't forget this:

```
alert.show();
```